# Parallel MonteCarlo: reproducibility or real randomness?

Tags: multithreading, random, parallel-processing, montecarlo

I'm preparing a college exam in parallel computing.
The main purpose is to speedup as much as possible a Montecarlo simulation about electron drift in earth magnetic field.
I've already developed something with two layers of parallelization:

- MPI used to make te code run on several machines
- OpenMP to run parallel simulation inside the single computer

Now comes the question: I would like to keep on-demand the task execution.
The fastest computer must be able to execute more work the the slower ones.
The problem partition is done via master-worker cycle, so there is no actual struggle about achieving this result.

Since the number of tasks (a block of n electrons to simulate) executed by a worker is not prior defined I have two roads to follow:

1. every thread in every worker has is own RNG initialized with random generated seed (different generation method). The unbalancing of the cluster will change results, but in this approach the result is as casual as possible.
2. every electron has his own seed, granting reproducibility of the simulation despite of which worker runs the single task. Must have a better RNG.

Lets's poll about this. What's your suggestion?

Have fun

gf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What to poll about here?

Clearly, only approach #2 is a feasible one. Each source particle starts with it's own and stable seed. It makes result reproducible AND debuggable (for a lack of better word).

Well-known Monte Carlo code MCNP5+ used this scheme for good, runs on multi-cores and MPI. To implement it you'll need RNG with fast skip-ahead (a.k.a. leapfrog or discard) feature. And there are quite a few of them. They are based upon fast exponent computation, paper by F. Brown, "Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Stride", Trans. Am. Nucl. Soc. (Nov. 1994). Basically, skip-ahead is log(N) with Brown approach.

Simplest version which is about the same as MCNP5 one is here https://github.com/Iwan-Zotow/LCG-PLE63

More complicated (and slower, but higher quality) RNG is here http://www.pcg-random.org/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.
Can you explain why I have to use a leapfrog RNG? I can't point it out.
ATM my code uses a low quality RNG on the master to generate seeds for workers' RNG (better, not best quality). Workers' ones generate seeds for Marsenne-Twister RNGs, one for each electron.
In this way I'm getting a 1:1 seed sequence to electron ratio that I suppose will ensure reproducibility of the simulation.
Is that approach ok?
Thanks in advance

gf

Comment: You cannot guarantee that sequences won't overlap. You hope they won't but you can't prove it. With fast leapfrog you start with single seed. For each electron you allocate say N_e = 10^4 numbers. Then for each node you set seed by leapfrogging by (N_n*N_e), which is with log(N) skip is really fast. On the node you start with node seed and before sourcing electron you jump by N_e. Everything is fast, reproducible and controllable. You could even count (usually in Debug mode) how many actual calls to RNG each electron tracking made, so if they overlap you could just increase N_e and be done.

Comment: Thanks again for your clearness.

I'll try to paraphrase what you wrote.
Lets say I have tasks of Ne electrons each.
Lets say the task will be executed with Nt threads.
There's only one pseudrandom number sequence, common to all threads, generated by a good RNG. Every thread has his own RNG clone.
Every time I start simulating an electron I jump to the first random value not yet used (using leapfrog instruction). In this way the same sequence (without overlapping) is common to all electrons. Am I right?

Comment: Pressed Enter instead of shift+enter. Sorry!

Comment: Yes, each thread has his own RNG clone. Each one is initialized with the the same default seed before simulation. MCNP5-like RNG (first link) has period of 2^63, about 10^18. General principle is overallocation of random numbers. So you allocate per single electron track lot more than necessary. Say 10^4 numbers when really electron track uses only 10^3. Per thread (single simulation) you overallocate to, lets say, 10^9 electrons tracks, thus guaranteed never overlap. Thus with 10 threads per node and 100 nodes you have total of 10^16 numbers used, well within period. To be continued...

Comment: Thus, with per track N_e = 10^4 and per thread N_t = 10^9, and each thread having same default RNG with default seed initialized. You start  node simulation by leapfrogging by N_e * N_t * node_rank * nof_threads_per_node). You might feel generous and set nof_threads_per_node equal to 100 for each node, why not, makes life easier. And then on top of that simulation by each thread is leapfrogged by N_e * N_t * thread_id. And that's it

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.
That's an awesome solution to keep on reproducibility as well as statistical significance.
I'll try to implement something like this in my code.
Have fun and a nice day

gf

Comment: You're welcome. To be honest, I never dealt with non-uniform cluster, where nodes differ in speed. You might want to think about doing calculation in bunches. Let's say your bunch has number of tracks N_b=10^5. Then you split your whole calc into number of bunches and then deliver bunches (their start seeds) to particular node, so faster node gets more bunches and slower node less. Just an idea...

Comment: Yep, I've already prepared something like this.
I just decide bunch-size and then deliver this to the single worker.
The whole thing was working well, but the result was dependent on execution sequence.
Anyhow, with your suggestion I can manage the forcing of a sleep(n seconds) (slow machine simulation) inside one of my workers keeping the run reproducible (aka same result)!

Comment: Just finished to implement your solution, using the best RNG (pcg-random) you suggested, and that's working as a charm. Thanks a lot, have a good everything! :)