# Monte-Carlo PI on cluster

Tags: random, cluster-computing, montecarlo

So, I'm designing a Monte-Carlo PI simulation on a GPU cluster.

Currently, I choose one random number generator algorithm, say XorShift7. And due to the algorithm limitation, for one seed, it can generates only 2^32 numbers, since it is a 32bit algorithm, and the sequence will repeat after 2^32 numbers. I let each cluster worker calculate a part of the whole sequence, and then reduce them.

The question is, I want to enlarge the random numbers. My idea is, I want to use multiple random number sequences, with different algorithm and different seed, for example:

```
cluster worker1: calc XorShift7(seed=0) from number0 to number2^31
cluster worker2: calc XorShift7(seed=0) from number2^31 to number2^32
cluster worker3: calc XorShift7(seed=1) from number0 to number2^31
cluster worker4: calc XorShift7(seed=1) from number2^31 to number2^32
cluster worker5: calc Mrg32k3a(seed=0) from number0 to number2^31
cluster worker6: calc Mrg32k3a(seed=0) from number2^31 to number2^32
cluster worker7: calc Mrg32k3a(seed=1) from number0 to number2^31
cluster worker8: calc Mrg32k3a(seed=1) from number2^31 to number2^32
```

Then I average the value of the 8 results from the 8 workers.

My question is, will this break the random number properties from a statistic perspective?

Comment: I would recommend to read discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991299/parallel-montecarlo-reproducibility-or-real-randomness

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, thanks and I checked that discussion, so I think you suggest use one RNG type and one seed in one simulation. thus the max numbers that I can use to do one PI simulation is the period of the RNG. To enlarge the random numbers that I can use more cluster power, I have to find better RNG with larger period.

Comment: Well, both RNGs mentioned in discussion have period WAY large than 2^32. Smallest RNG period is 2^63 or about 10^18. So you set initial seed to 1 and then for each node you do fast skip-ahead by lets say i*10^12. So each node has enough random numbers to run and you could have at minimum 10^6 (one million!) nodes. And your 2^32 is about 4*10^9 for comparison

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, thanks, yes, the period of the rng I use is too small, because they are GPU implemented, so I need find at least a 64bit GPU RNG. BTW, since calculation of PI need x and y, so I think I can setup 2 RNGs, and with 2 different seeds, for the point's x and y, so I get the full period, otherwise, I have only half the period for points.

Comment: Well, CUDA does support 64bit integers (long longs), so you could just port RNG from the link and use it.