# One Random instance per thread, seeded by the original Random instance to attain reproducibility

Tags: java, random, distribution, uniform-distribution

I need to do `1000` calculations, each one based on a random number.
The entire run needs to be **reproducible**.

In a single threaded environment, I just create random based on a seed and use that for each calculation:

```
Random random = new Random(37);
for (Calculation c : calculations) {
    c.doCalculation(r.nextInt());
}
```

In a multi threaded enviromnent, where I have `10` threads, I 'd have a seeded random seed the thread Random's:

```
Random initRandom = new Random(37);
for (List<Calculation> p : calculationPartitions) {
    final Random threadRandom = new Random(initRandom.nextLong());
    executorService.submit(() -> {
        for (Calculation c : p) {
            c.doCalculation(threadRandom.nextInt());
        }
    });
}
// Merge the calculation results back in the same order as the calculationPartitions
...
```

**Is this a good idea?** Is it still an evenly distributed random in general? The fact that each `threadRandom` is seeded by the `initRandom`, does it not break the uniform distribution?

For reproducible reasons, I cannot share 1 global random, as some threads might run faster than others in some runs, so they would not always call the global random in the same order (and the contention could cause performance degradation).

Comment: `Random` generates evenly distributed numbers, so answer is: Yes.

Comment: This is a reasonable idea. If you share a random, they are synchronized which makes using the same random in different threads difficult. You might even go so far as to use something other than a `List<Calculation>` but a custom class that contains the `List`, and also contains the `Random`.

Comment: @Andreas so the fact that the threads all use a Random that is seeded by a random number from the original Random doesn't break that uniform distribution guarantee?

Comment: The fact that the Random is seeded with a particular value (hardcoded or from elsewhere), doesn't change the fact that Random will generate evenly distributed numbers from then on. If a seeded Random didn't do that, you couldn't even to this for the single threaded environment, now could you?

Comment: Geoffrey, please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28991299/parallel-montecarlo-reproducibility-or-real-randomness and discussion within, it might give you some insights...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get an even distribution of numbers via Random, however the order that the each list of Calculation objects in your list will run is not guaranteed so if these then pass the result to a shared list the order may vary over runs.

Comment: Lists retain order, why do you think their order is not guaranteed?

Comment: Executor service has no guarantee of what order the Runnables submitted will run in.

Comment: Because they are threads running independent of each other? Of course; when they would be just "posting" their results somewhere, that order within that result set can be completely ... random.

Comment: I didn't parse your sentence well the first time. Your edit helps to make it more clear. Of course the execution order could change, but the `Random` associated with a particular calculation would not change.

Comment: True, however to make it truly reproducible the user may need to take the thread run order randomness into account depending on their needs.

Comment: @UserF40 Order of execution doesn't matter if the `doCalculation()` simply saves the result back on the `Calculation` object. Of course, if each thread prints/sends the results *as they occur*, the results will be printed/sent in semi-random order ("semi" since order of calculations within a partition stays ordered), but that won't matter as long as results always identify the source `Calculation`. A result without origin is meaningless, see [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)#The_Hitchhiker.27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy).

Comment: True, we can only speculate without the full implementation.

Comment: @UserF40 Fair point, I 've added a comment in the code to make it clear that the results are being merged back in original order, so they can be printed in original order. Or put differently: presume that each calculation has an id and they are being sorted by id on the main thread before printing.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically about the uniform distribution, it seems to be ok with 1 random location per 10 pixels:

[image: distribution]

Oh wait, with 1 random location per 1 pixel, the seeded threaded approach even seems better!? In a perfect uniform distribution (for size 250000) it would be all black:

[image]

Left:

```
public class SingleRandomProof extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    public static final int SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleRandomProof proof = new SingleRandomProof();
        proof.pack();
        proof.setVisible(true);
        proof.doCalc();
    }

    private JLabel panel;

    public SingleRandomProof() throws HeadlessException {
        super("1 random");
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    private void doCalc() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Random r = new Random(37);
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            int position = r.nextInt(SIZE);
            g.fillRect(position % HEIGHT, position / HEIGHT, 1, 1);
        }
        panel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }

}
```

Right:

```
public class SeededThreadRandomProof extends JFrame {

    public static final int WIDTH = 500;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 500;
    public static final int SIZE = WIDTH * HEIGHT;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SeededThreadRandomProof proof = new SeededThreadRandomProof();
        proof.pack();
        proof.setVisible(true);
        proof.doCalc();
    }

    private JLabel panel;

    public SeededThreadRandomProof() throws HeadlessException {
        super("10 seeded randoms");
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        panel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        setContentPane(panel);
    }

    private void doCalc() {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        Random initRandom = new Random(37);
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            Random r = new Random(initRandom.nextLong());
            for (int i = 0; i < SIZE / 10; i++) {
                int position = r.nextInt(SIZE);
                g.fillRect(position % HEIGHT, position / HEIGHT, 1, 1);
            }
        }
        panel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }

}
```

Comment: And how it is related to the question of **REPRODUCIBLE**?

Comment: This just answers the part of the question if it's still uniformly distributed random (I removed the threading complexity in the code above, but adding threads won't make a difference). I still had doubts about that. I 've accepted the other answer as that answers most of the question.